# SQL Command to get all rows from a specific set of groups

Tags: sql, group-by

Let say I have the following table (The ID is self incremental)

```
ID    Name    Serial   Status
0     Pie     A        Fail
1     Pie     A        Fail
2     Pie     A        Pass
3     Pie     B        Fail
4     Pie     B        Pass
5     Pie     C        Pass
6     Pie     C        Fail
```

How can I get all the rows where the last row of each Group By (Name, Serial) is Pass?

This is the result I should get from the query. The serial C is removed since the last entry of the group by (Name, Serial) is 'Fail'

```
 ID    Name    Serial   Status
 0     Pie     A        Fail
 1     Pie     A        Fail
 2     Pie     A        Pass
 3     Pie     B        Fail
 4     Pie     B        Pass
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS?  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this (assuming SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE(
    ID INT, 
    Name VARCHAR(10), 
    Serial VARCHAR(1), 
    [Status] VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(0, 'Pie', 'A', 'Fail')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(1, 'Pie', 'A', 'Fail')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(2, 'Pie', 'A', 'Pass')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(3, 'Pie', 'B', 'Fail')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(4, 'Pie', 'B', 'Pass')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(5, 'Pie', 'C', 'Pass')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES(6, 'Pie', 'C', 'Fail')

SELECT * 
FROM @myTable
WHERE Serial NOT IN
(
    --Get all Serial that end with a 'Fail'
    SELECT T1.Serial
    FROM @myTable T1
    JOIN (
        --Get Max ID for a serial
        SELECT MAX(ID) as [ID] FROM @myTable GROUP BY Serial
    ) T2 ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
    WHERE T1.[Status] = 'Fail'
)
ORDER BY [ID]
```

or if you prefer `NOT EXISTS` (which is usually faster than `NOT IN`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM @myTable T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 
        T1.Serial
    FROM @myTable T1
    JOIN (
        --Get Max ID for a serial
        SELECT MAX(ID) as [ID] FROM @myTable GROUP BY Serial
    ) T2 ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
    WHERE 
        T1.[Status] = 'Fail' 
        AND T1.[Serial] = T.[Serial]
)
ORDER BY [ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to improve readability by implementing as a series of sequential steps:

1. Get max ids
2. Get serials for max ids that have status 'Fail'
3. Remove those rows that match the serials

It would look like this:

```
with maxIds as ( --Get max Ids
                SELECT MAX(ID) as [ID] FROM myTable GROUP BY Serial
 ), 
serials as ( -- Get serials for max ids that have status 'Fail'
           SELECT T1.Serial FROM myTable T1 JOIN maxIds ON T1.[ID] = maxIds.[ID] WHERE [Status] = 'Fail' 
)  
select * from myTable where serial not in (select * from serials) -- Remove serials that match
```